# How to display data from data base in panel

Tags: c#, .net

i want to display data in panels from data base ,i wrote this code but i don't know how to add panel for each data .

```
private void Utilisateur_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            disp_data();

        }
        public void disp_data()
        {

            databaseConnection.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = databaseConnection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Nom_Utilisateur, Prenom_Utilisateur, 
            Type_Utilisateur FROM utilisateurs";

            using (MySqlDataReader oReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (oReader.Read())
                {


                    label2.Text=oReader.GetString("Nom_Utilisateur");
                    label3.Text = oReader.GetString("Prenom_Utilisateur");
                    label4.Text = oReader.GetString("Type_Utilisateur");

                }


            }

            databaseConnection.Close();
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pElUY.png)

Comment: The easiest way is put a DGV into the panel.  Then change you read code to use a DataAdapter and fill a DataTable with results and use datagridview1.DataSource = dt where dt is the DataTable.  See sample code on following.  Sample code uses DataSet but I would replace DataSet with DataTable. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataAdapter.htm

Comment: You should not be directly reading databases in 2019.  There are many simpler methods like Dapper or EntityFramework.

Comment: @Neil I think _should not_ is too strong, but _don't have to_ seems about right. And I would not say setting up EF was 'simple': navigation properties, N+1 queries, the abyss of migrations..

Comment: @stuartd A trainee painter would be told not make brushes, a new builder would be told not to make bricks.  Why should we allow learner developers to use 'stone-age' tools, rather than modern ones?  There are so many minefields when accessing databases, so let's teach the learners not to do it.  Yes EF is complicated, but Dapper is very easy for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (MySqlDataReader oReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (oReader.Read())
            {
                Label label1 = new Label();
                label1.Text = oReader.GetString("Nom_Utilisateur");
                Controls.Add(label1); //controls can be panel on your page

                 other labels

            }


        }
```

Comment: i want to add panel for each data

Comment: you can create panel each time dynamic

Comment: you need one declaration panel where you will be add new panel